# What is the equivalent code for the asp.net core DI framework from this example using Ninject?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, ninject, unity-container

I've been looking at using CQS pattern with EF Core within an asp.net Core web application.

I found this sample, which seems to be what I want however the DI container used is Ninject.

I can't seem to be able to translate the Ninject configuration into the inbuilt DI container in asp.net core.

Specifically my problem is with these lines:

```
Bind<IQueryFactory>().ToMethod(t => new QueryFactory(x => Container.Current.Resolve(x))).InTransientScope();
            Bind<ICommandsFactory>()
                .ToMethod(t => new CommandFactory(x => (object[]) Container.Current.ResolveAll(x)))
                .InTransientScope();
```

I have gotten this far:

```
services.AddTransient<IQueryFactory>(qf => new QueryFactory(q => q));
```

But I'm not sure how to actually do this part in asp.net core di container:

```
Container.Current.Resolve(x)
```

Comment: https://github.com/Code-First/CQS-Sample/blob/master/TestApp/IoC/Configuration.cs - The sample I have been using.

Comment: It might be easier to solve the problem without referencing the Ninject example. What is it that you need to inject or resolve? There are some patterns for injecting a delegate which is a method of a class resolved from the container.

Comment: I've implemented the whole sample, so I need to resolve the query or command object(s) using that factory pattern. I just can't figure out how.

Comment: It's largely because I don't use Ninject, but it's really hard to even tell what it is that needs to be registered and resolved. If someone comes along who knows Ninject it might be more obvious to them. But if you can show what needs to be registered and resolved then it may be easier to see how to do it. I suspect it might be something like [this](https://github.com/vkhorikov/CqrsInPractice/blob/master/After/src/Api/Utils/HandlerRegistration.cs) but that could be off by a mile.

Comment: The query factory class, QueryFactory, should resolve the implementation of a query class at runtime. I believe I understand how it's supposed to work, just not how to implement it correctly with the .net core di container.

`code`queryFactory
.ResolveQuery<IActiveUsersQuery>()
.Execute();`code`

Comment: Thanks for the assistance @ScottHannen - I've figured it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would seem I was overthinking it and I have resolved my problem.

```
services.AddTransient<IQueryFactory>
    (serviceProvider => new QueryFactory(serviceProvider.GetService));
```

Comment: You should mark this as the answer. The exact same question came up today, so it's helpful.