# What is the Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection (IServiceCollection) equivalent of Ninject's Bind<TService>().ToMethod?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core

I Used to do such things in *Ninject* :

```
kernel.Bind<IDatabase>().ToMethod(context =>
    RedisConnectionFactory.GetConnection().GetDatabase(              
int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RedisConnectionIdsDatabase"])));
```

To Bind an *Interface* `IDatabase` to a **method**. Now I have switched to **dotnet core** and I want to know that **dotnet core dependency injector** is capable of such thing?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to create a factory. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54127414/using-factory-pattern-with-asp-net-core-dependency-injection

Comment: I want the function/method to return an Instance Of `IDatabase` and the DI system to inject this instance whenever declared.

Comment: Here's the same question that came up yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56260643/what-is-the-equivalent-code-for-the-asp-net-core-di-framework-from-this-example#comment99143422_56260643. The confusion (for me anyway) is that Ninject's terminology is very different. I usually hear this described as "resolving using a factory method." It's a familiar concept described in an unfamiliar way.

Comment: @ScottHannen That is the answer to my question.

Comment: `ToMethod` confusing name for the factory delegate...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can something like this

```
services.AddTransient<IDatabase>((sp) =>
{
    return RedisConnectionFactory
        .GetConnection().GetDatabase(int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RedisConnectionIdsDatabase"]));
});
```